# symfony 2.1 injection doctrine in service

Tags: symfony, service, entitymanager

I need to get some data in my db and the current user, so I use the entity manager and `security.context` in my service

I have this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object
>   in path/to/file on line 84

service.yml :

```
services:
ns_messagerie.letterboxcore:
    class: ns\MessagerieBundle\LetterBoxCore\LetterBoxCore
    arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Dependency injection :

```
class nsMessagerieExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

And my service :

```
class LetterBoxCore {

    protected $securityContext;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct( $securityContext,  $entityManager) {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

public function countNbNotRead(Utilisateur $user = null, Discussion $discussions) {
//...
}

public function getAllDiscussion(Utilisateur $user = null, $all = null) { 
// line 84:
$list = $em->getRepository('nsMessagerieBundle:ParticipantMessagerie')
                              ->findBy(array('participant' => $user,
                                             'supprimer' => $all
                                      )
                                 );

}

public function getBAL(Utilisateur $user = null) {
// Call the method countNbNotRead and GetAllDiscussion
}
```

Comment: Can you paste other LetterBoxCore class methods ? And also the current "path/to/file" ?

Comment: Thank for you help.

This is the complete message :
Fatal error: Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object in /var/www/project/src/ns/MessagerieBundle/LetterBoxCore/LetterBoxCore.php on line 84 

And for the complete the class I have edit my previous message

Comment: Replace `$em->getRepository` by `$this->em->getRepository`

Comment: omg stupid error... Thank you so much!